# Who follows Obi-Wan Kenobi and Luke Skywalker in Mos Eisley?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, a-new-hope

Luke Skywalker, Obi-Wan Kenobi, and the droids are followed by an informant when go to the Millennium Falcon for the first time. The informant tells the stormtroopers that our heroes have gone to the docking bay with the Millennium Falcon.

The informant is wearing a hood, has really big sunglasses, and a huge nose.

Who is that? How does he know the stormtroopers are looking for Luke,  Obi-Wan, and the droids? (Is it just a matter of the stormtroopers put out an offer for any info on an astromech droid?)

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Garindan

Comment: I kind of love how Lucas went through the entire original trilogy and invented little backstories for literally every character who appears in the background.  Even if it was, in reality, just to sell action figures, it adds a level of depth to the universe I really enjoy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

His name was **Garindan**, and according to *Ultimate Star Wars*, he was

> hired by the local Imperial authorities to locate the droids

[Garindan: Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Garindan)